# Insert image path and data in MySQL database

Tags: php

I have two pages: *displayhotels.php* and *addrooms.php*. When I click on the add rooms link which is on the *displayhotels.php* page, it fetches the hotel name and displays it on the *addrooms.php* page. Now, I need to insert the hotel name and other variables in a table. For some reason, the image path and data are not storing in the db. However, the image is updating in the folder.

```
if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
echo "";
}else{
$file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']

['tmp_name']));
$image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]

["tmp_name"],"rooms/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$image="rooms/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$rnum = $_POST['rnum'];
$rtype = $_POST['rtype'];
$people = $_POST['people'];
$cond = $_POST['cond'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$rooms = $_POST['rooms'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `room`(`hotel_name`, `roomNum`,`roomType`, 

`noOfPeople`, `conditions`, `price`, `rooms`, `image`) VALUES 

('$name','$rnum', '$rtype', '$people', '$cond', '$price', '$rooms', 

'$image')";
```

Comment: You need to run your query.

Comment: what is $image = $_POST['image']; ?

Comment: print_r($_POST); chk r u getting values

Comment: Also show yur HTML form

Answer (score 0):

You are first making correct `$image` variable:

```
$image="rooms/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
```

But then you overwrite it with a wrong one:

```
$image = $_POST['image'];
```

So you need to remove this line and you'll do fine i guess.

Comment: Okay, I removed this line but it still does not insert anything. Do you think there is something wrong with the insert query?

Answer (score 0):

**Few debugging tips:**

First of all add `error_reporting()` in your code.

Than check are you getting values from HTML form by using:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Also check are you using proper name attributes in input field?

**Error in your code:**

In your query you didn't defined the variable:

```
$name
```

You missed `hotel_name` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging with a logger and using `tail -f [log file name]` from the terminal if using LAMP to step through the code. Are you sure `$_POST['submit']` is set? How are you connecting to the db? This isn't shown in the code. Maybe the file I/O is working fine (the image updates in the folder) but you're not connecting to the db and the problem isn't the sql statement itself but the actual connection.

Also, look into using prepared statements to make your code more secure, and not directly accessing $_POST variables. See http://php.net/manual/it/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php for more information.

Comment: It is working fine now! I have actually removed $_POST['submit']. And yes, there is a connection to the db; I used the include statement. Thank you everyone :) However, I wanted to know how removing the $_POST['submit'] affects the query?

Comment: $_POST['submit'] should correspond with a field in the form you used to submit the post data, likely something along the lines of <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1"/>, in cases where the form html and the script used to process it are contained in the same page. When the page first loads (no one has clicked submit) the submit variable is not set, but after form submission it is. Depending on this condition, you can execute different code for the two cases. You may have forgotten to include this field in your form or have called it something different, resulting in dead code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! It is going to be of great help.